# Django "server error occured"

Tags: django, python-3.x

In short words: Even though im following tutorial perfectly, and get no errors when starting server I get "a server error occured. Please contact the administrator" error when i open the site. Here is prompt i get in pycharm:

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\Users\Username\Downloads\WinPython-64bit-3.6.2.0Qt5\python-3.6.2.amd64\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" runserver C:/Users/Username/PycharmProjects/strona2
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 14, 2018 - 18:27:17
Django version 2.0.6, using settings 'strona2.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Full story: I'm a total newb in a subject so please forgive if my problem is trivial. I'm following this tutorial: [first app in Django using Pycharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-and-running-your-first-django-project.html#launch-server), and up to the point of "performing administrative functions" everything went well. I added superuser, performed migrations, opened server, and even though i get no errors in pycharm somehow an error occurs on site. The previous parts of tutorial work. For example 127.0.0.1:8000/polls works just as it should while 127.0.0.1:8000/admin doesn't. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have debug enabled? 

DEBUG=True in settings.py

Comment: did add `admin` app in your project settings?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when going through a Django tutorial (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial02/)

My problem ended up being the value that I had used for the TIME_ZONE in settings.py. After I had switched that back to e.g. 'UTC', the admin page worked fine.